# SQL Server Create Dynamic Table with different table names based on a template or an existing table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

My team is creating a high volume data processing tool. The idea is to take a 30,000 line batch file and bulk load it into a table and then process the records use parallel processing.

The part I'm stuck on is creating dynamic tables. We want to create a new physical table for each file that we receive. The tables will be purged from our system by a separate process after they are completed.

The part I'm stuck on is creating dynamic tables. For each batch file we receive I need to create a new physical file with a unique table name.

I have the base structure for the table and I intend to create unique table names using a combination of date/time stamp and a guid (dashes converted to underscore characters).

I could do this easily enough in a stored procedure but I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Here is what I have considered...

1. Templates in SQL Server Management Studio. This is a GUI tool built into Management Studio (from Management Studio Ctrl+Alt+T) that allows you to define different sql objects including a table and specify parameters. This seems like it would work, however it appears that this is a  GUI tool and not something that I could call from a stored procedure.
2. Stored Procedure. I could put everything into a stored procedure and build my file name and schema into a nvarchar(max) string and use sp_executesql to create the table. This might be the way to accomplish my goal but I wonder if there is a better way.
3. Stored Procedure with an existing table as a template. I could define a base table and then query sys.columns & sys.dataypes to create a string representing the new table. This would allow me to add columns to the base table without having to update my stored procedure. I'm not sure if this is a better approach.

I'm wondering if any Stack Overflow folks have solved a similar requirements. What are your recommendations.

Comment: Polybase + external tables: https://www.sqlshack.com/enhanced-polybase-sql-2019-external-tables-using-t-sql/

Comment: Polybase might work. Thanks